# Differences between interfaces and abstract classes in Java?

Tags: java, oop, interface, abstract-class

What should I answer the question: "What are differences between interfaces and abstract classes in Java?" in the interview? Can I answer with format like before Java8 and after Java8? Please makes sense for me...

What are differences between interfaces and abstract classes in Java?

Comment: *"Can I answer with format like before Java8 and after Java8?"* - Well ... the addition of `default` methods in Java 8 has certainly made a comparison of interfaces and abstract classes more complicated.  So ... yes ... you should include that in ... what you tell your interviewer.  (And of course, that means you need to understand `default` methods and what they bring to Java.)